# Mac OS X app that expands a directory into the cloud, allowing to store more than local disk can contain

Tags: osx, file-synchronization, cloud-storage

Say I have 200 GB of disk space left on my machine. Over time, I want to add 250 GB worth of files to a directory on this machine. Is there an application, similar to Google Drive, that will sync all 250 GB worth of files to the cloud but keeps a local copy of the most recently used 200 GB worth of files? Ideally, the additional 50 GB worth of files would be visible as icons but their actual contents would not exist on my local machine until I try to access them.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) (cross-platform) might be capable of this. It's based on Git (which is used to manage its MetaData), but lets you define which "real content" you want to *keep* locally and which should just be "available on demand".